Is there a way to view Spring Data Jpa's Execution query before executing?
I am currently working on Simple Bulletin project and new to Hibernate/JPA/Spring data JPA.
While working on the Spring data Jpa's deleteAll() code,
I noticed
deleteAll() executes select and delete query each.
For example, when there are 1000 rows in Table, then 1000 select and 1000 delete query executes.
In order to effectively exectue the query I want to execute,
I have to use @Modify/@Query JPQL.
So, the thing I want to know is this.
Is there an official document of how the JPA / Spring Data JPA function actually exectues the query before executing?
Like, is there an JPA / Hibernate /Spring Data JPA's document about it?
Or is there any way to know the executing query before executing in code?
I have looked at the spring data's jpa document, and I couldn't find it.
Thank you in advance.

Does this answer your question? How can I log SQL statements in Spring Boot?

but doesn't really answer my question though.
I want to know how spring data jpa's query execution behaves "before" executing. So Logging the SQL statements is not an option for my question..
I think there should be an official document of how the JPA queries are executed and exists somehow.. but can't find it.
Thank you by the way. The link you gave was a great article,

Spring Data doesn't execute anything, it only is a wrapper around JPA. How to log the queries that are executed is part of your JPA provider not spring data jpa.

If I'm using hibernate, then it's more of how hibernate executes rather than how spring data jpa executes the query. I'll have to understand the jpa-hibernate-spring_data_jpa relation...

Spring Data JPA has its Reference Documentation
There is the JPA specification
But it seems what you are really interested in is the source code of Spring Data JPA. A break point here might be a good entry point in understanding, what is going on.
